# Which system for object detection is used in Yolo?

Tags: object-detection, image-recognition, conv-neural-network, yolo

I tried to find which convolutional neural network is used in Yolo project but, unfortunately, I did not get this information. Which system for object detection is used in Yolo? R-CNN?

Answer (score 1):

The original YOLO network is inspired by the GoogLeNet model.
There is no R-CNN in YOLO. They both use very different techniques to detect objects in images. R-CNN for instance predicts bounding boxes for certain regions and checks with a classifier if there is an object. YOLO on the other hand will look at the full image and make it's predictions from there.

For more information you should read the original paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02640.pdf